# wp_editor (tinymce not showing interface/switching tabs);

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I've created a custom plugin for a newsletter.  All is fine with my tables, database, etc.  I'm trying to create a WYSIWYG to allow users to add HTML elements without knowing any HTML.. however, the wp_editor is not being displayed correctly as shown here (it's missing all of the buttons and I cannot switch between the visual/text editor):

[image: what the wp_editor looks like]

When I click to switch tabs I get an "**Uncaught ReferenceError: switchEditors is not defined**" error.

I'm very confused as Wordpress is using the same wp_editor code to allow users to edit posts/pages which are working just fine in this same Wordpress installation.

What about my plugin could be causing this to break?  I have spent too much time trying to figure it out on my own (Googling and all) to no avail.

I've tried passing many different parameters to wp_editor in trying to fix this, but here is my initial, most simplistic attempt ($campaign->template just loads the template text from the database which shows up fine--though the color is white by default in the screenshot):

```
wp_editor(stripslashes($campaign->template), 'template');
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  I am behind on this project.

Comment: Try to set `define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);` in your **wp-config.php` and check it again

Comment: @AdrianPreuss - tried that to no avail.. thanks, though!

Comment: Did you fix the issue?

Comment: @BriceArgenson - Not technically; I simply moved to a custom WYSIWYG editor.

Answer (score 0):

I know this sounds stupid but check your upload folder via FTP for any large files. A client of mine had a similar issue and after a bit of trial and error found the issue wasn't admin, plugins or theme but a couple of files under uploads/2014/03 which were 10MB+ in size. After resizing them and overwriting the original file admin worked again.